# Alter tables and columns in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I was trying to alter some column fields in my MySQL table by modifying the class "test" below and messed it up in a bad way, I also deleted the migration files.

I am new to models and migrations but I am trying to understand on how to modify a table or columns in a proper way.

1) I have seen people modify the test class directly, for example if I would like to change the decimal_places to 5 instead of 4 they just changed the number and ran makemigrations. This is how I did it, sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't recognize any changes. And now the last time it messed up my unique_together() function.

After some research it seems that I should create a table with class test(models.Model) and then from there on If I would like to change something I should use the ALTER TABLE function?

2) Since I now have ruined a well functioning database I would like to delete my table and create a new models.py and do the setup all over again. Is this a "proper" way of doing it or is there something smoother than just DROP TABLE and deleting the models.py and migrations?

```
# Create your models here.
class test(models.Model):
 birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
 published = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
 city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4, null=True)
 something = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'test'
    unique_together = (('published', 'city', 'price'),)

def __str__(self):
    return self.names
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your issues were caused by you by adding a `unique_together` that includes a field that can have `NULL` values.

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4, null=True)
```

The field `price` is allowed to have `NULL` values in your database, as you defined `null=True`.

Your `unique_together` contains this nullable field however:

```
unique_together = (('published', 'city', 'price'),)
```

Most likely you have created multiple `test` objects in your database with no price specified. Then you created your `unique_together` restraint, which is violated because multiple entries have a `NULL` value in the `price` column.

The easiest option to fix it is probably this:

- delete all your entries with `test.objects.all().delete()`
- run the migrations (`python manage.py migrate`) which will now be possible as your constraint is no longer violated
- then create the entries again

You will get a `ValidationError` when creating them as your constraint will be violated again. You need to figure out how to handle your conflicting entries, e.g. by changing one of the values (`published`, `city` or `price`) or just not storing the entries that cause the error.

Another option is to update your entries manually to remove any conflicts. Most likely it is enough to add a price to each entry to fix it.

You could also empty your `test` table through SQL. In this case you also need to get rid of the entries in the `django_migrations` table in your database, delete the migrations and run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

You should be able to fix your issues by deleting your `test` objects, running `migrate` and then creating them again though.

Answer (score -1):

1) Try `migrate your_app zero` if you still have your table and migrations
2) Delete migration files
3) Then rewrite your model if needed
4) `makemigrations` and `migrate`